# JPA discriminator column problem

Tags: java, jpa, subclass

Hallo all.
I have this set of classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="COD_TIPORAPPORTO",
                     discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.CHAR, length=1)
public abstract class Rapporto implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5567166522882040440L;
 
  @Id
  @Column(name = "COD_RAPPORTO")  
  protected Long codiceRapporto;
```

And this sublass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="S_MC_CC_CCCLIENTI")
@DiscriminatorValue("1 ")
public class ContoCorrente extends Rapporto {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3380622649760983262L;

  @Column(name = "DESC_DIVISA")
  private String divisa;
```

The problem is on the discriminator value: on the table the column is CHAR(2).

When I make the getItemById on the subclass all works fine: this is the generated eclipselink sql: (I replaced the column definition with * for easy to read)

```
[EL Fine]: 2011-01-16 16:01:14.531--ServerSession(5230193)--Connection(11601738)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--  SELECT * FROM S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI t0, S_MC_CC_CCCLIENTI t1 WHERE ((t0.COD_RAPPORTO = ?) AND ((t1.COD_RAPPORTO = t0.COD_RAPPORTO) AND (t0.COD_TIPORAPPORTO = ?)))
 bind => [1120676, 1 ]
```

If I change the `@DiscriminatorValue("1")` removing the space the data is not found: this is the relative generated sql

```
[EL Fine]: 2011-01-16 16:03:46.671--ServerSession(5230193)--Connection(11601738)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT * FROM S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI t0, S_MC_CC_CCCLIENTI t1 WHERE ((t0.COD_RAPPORTO = ?) AND ((t1.COD_RAPPORTO = t0.COD_RAPPORTO) AND (t0.COD_TIPORAPPORTO = ?)))
 bind => [1120676, 1]
```

Note that the two queries work fine with TOAD: both the t0.COD_TIPORAPPORTO = '1 ' one, even the t0.COD_TIPORAPPORTO = '1'.

OK: so I think that the `@DiscriminatorValue("1 ")` is correct.

Now I make an association many-to-many with the super class Rapporto as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693948/jpa-one-to-many-association-to-an-entity-with-inheritancestrategy-inheritancety)

If I mantain the `@DiscriminatorValue("1 ")` I get

```
[EL Warning]: 2011-01-16 16:09:33.421--ServerSession(29839159)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [1] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(it.alten.intesasanpaolo.contratto.domain.core.rapporto.Rapporto --> [DatabaseTable(S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI)])
```

If I change the `@DiscriminatorValue("1")` removing the space all work fine but I receive no data (even If the data is present on DB).

I dunno what to do....
Any idea?

Kind regards

Massimo

Comment: Have you tried DiscriminatorType.STRING? String "1 " not equals "1" for sure. If eclipselink thinks otherwise, there must be some trimming options in eclipselink configuration i believe. Other options are using table views or @NamedNativeQuery instead of @Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database seems to have an issue with char comparison with spaces when using binding.  What database are you using?

There are several possible solutions, first I would check with your JDBC driver to see if it has any fixes or options to solve this.

One option is to set "eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters"="false" in your persistence.xml, this should resolve the issue.

Another solution is to disable char trimming in EclipseLink, (this one does not seem to be exposed to JPA persistence properties (please log a bug), so you need to use a SessionCustomizer to set it)
session.getLogin().setShouldTrimStrings(false);

A more involved solution is to use a DescriptorCustomizer to set your own ClassExtractor on the descriptor to use you own code to determine the class.

If you can change the data, then I would recommend just updating any '1 ' to '01' then you can just use '01' as the indicator.

Comment: Oracle 10g. I'm using jdbc oracle driver 10.2. I tried the eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters"="false" and now it works. ;) Great. I will try also the others solutions. Kind regards. Massimo

Comment: _Another solution is to disable char trimming in EclipseLink, (this one does not seem to be exposed to JPA persistence properties (please log a bug), so you need to use a SessionCustomizer to set it) session.getLogin().setShouldTrimStrings(false);_ I tried this way and I wrote my SessionCustomizer: now how must I configure it in myu application? Kind regards. Massimo

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the values in your database contain a trailing space. I'd suggest to run a query against the table and remove the trailing whitespace. Then have the discriminator value be `"1"` (no space)

In fact, if you are going to use numbers anyway, you should use `DiscriminatorType.INTEGER`

Comment: The column table is defined as CHAR(2). I tried to remove it but is not like a varchar, so in effect I don't think this is possible. I need to say to JPA to make a TRIM when it handle that column. Do you think is possible? Kind regards

Comment: can't you change it to varchar? Or perhaps - get the values out, delete the column completely, and create a new column, inserting the values. The new column better be of a numeric type.

Comment: What a pity, I cannot. I have a legacy database with 5 millions of record; is a not admitted operation.

Comment: I tried to change the column type in Number, and now all work fine. So the problem is really the column definition (Char(2)). I cannot change the column type: any idea? I need to make a trim on that column.