# JPA from EclipseLink to which provider?

Tags: jpa, provider

Hallo all.
I'm using EclipseLink as JPA provider in our project. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706102/jpa-discriminator-column-problem)
we have e big problem with char trimming with a DB char column with EclipseLink

I tried the way to remove the jdbc bind parameter but I cannot make this change for production environment: I tried to write my own SessionCustomizer but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class ContrattoSessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer#customize(org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session)
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello.....");
        DatabaseLogin login = (DatabaseLogin)session.getDatasourceLogin();
        login.setShouldTrimStrings(false);

    }

}
```

I would like to migrate from EclipseLink to another JPA provider; yesterday I tried with hibernate but unfortunately to migrate to this provider I need to change my domain model, since it seems that hibernate does not support some mapping definition that I used with eclipse link.

Is there another good provider to test without make changes to my domain model mapping?

Kind regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

Can't see how changing providers will help you, as it is a database issue.
You seemed to state that you solved the issue by disabling parameter binding?
Are you registering your SessionCustomizer in your persistence.xml?